# How to parse both Int and Float in JSON in Crystal?

Tags: crystal-lang

Crystal JSON complains that it can't cast Int to Float, code below throws exception

```
JSON.parse("{\"v\":1}")["v"].as_f
```

How to parse it? In case when some values are Int "1" and some Floats "1.1"?

Comment: This was discussed here: https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/8618.

Answer (score 1):

Crystal is comparatively strict with types here. You have to be more explicit.

Option 1.

Implement your own method. I'd recommend use a different name.

```
struct JSON::Any
  def to_f : Float64?
    case @raw
    when Float64 then @raw.as(Float64)
    when Int then @raw.as(Int).to_f
    end
  end
end
```

You can then call it as `JSON.parse("{\"v\":1}")["v"].as_f`

Option 2.

Inside your code do a check first.

```
my_v = JSON.parse("{\"v\":1}")["v"]
if my_v.as_f?
  my_v.as_f
elsif my_v.as_i?
  my_v.to_i.to_f
end
```